# Why is the newer/faster Java 8 way of sorting acting worse?

Tags: java, performance, sorting, java-8, java-stream

```
List<Point> pixels = new ArrayList<>(width * height); // 1280*960

for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        pixels.add(new Point(x, y));

// Java 7 sorting
Collections.sort(pixels, comparator);

// Java 8 sorting
pixels = pixels.stream().parallel().sorted(comparator).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

When using any sorting method, I get slow performance at first and it improves later. I expect this, because the JIT compiler needs time to optimize the high-use code.

The weird thing is, the old sorter is a little slow at first, while the new sorter much more so, more than 60% slower. After a while, the new sorter becomes faster, as expected. But the way that the first two/three executions are so slow is simply unacceptable.

```
Java 7 collection sorter
0.258992413
0.265509443
0.536536068
0.117830618
0.136303916
0.111004611
0.134771877
0.108078261

Java 8 stream sorter
0.631757108
0.868032669
0.076455248
0.087101852
0.070401965
0.056989645
0.072018371
0.078908912
0.074237648
```

Specs:
CPU: Intel I7 3770 (8-core 8M/1M/128K cache)
cmd: javaw -server -cp bin Myclass

- Has anyone else experienced worse performance of newer (stream) operations?
- Is there a way to fix this slowness? (without inducing start-up delays)

Comment: **How are you benchmarking this?**. If you are not using [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) or similar you can safely disregard these "benchmarks".

Comment: 1. `System.nanoTime()/1e9` before and after this bunch of code.

Comment: As above. You can safely ignore these values.

Comment: 2. Eyeballing. The GUI freezes for 0.86 seconds and I easily feel this.

Comment: Why on early are you sorting on the EDT??

Comment: P.S. I am rather unconvinced that `parallel` will help your here. Not least because, as you can see, you have to create an entirely new `List`.

Comment: FYI, with `.parallel()` it runs ~80% faster here.

Comment: You need to show the code behind those numbers. They are meaningless otherwise. It is true that it will be slower for the first few executions when lambdas are involved. But when your program is in production, the first few executions are rapidly done and, one day in, this is nothing to worry about.

Comment: It's not a production application but a science experiment. I think the closest comparable thing out there are 'demos'. Things you run, watch animating, then close. Over and over. Especially while still in development and I have to restart it a lot to add or tune features.

Comment: This is pretty much a conscious design decision on Java's part to accept initial slowness.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem.  I've got to assume the new method is probably more complex, which explains why it is slower at first.  But both algorithms become optimized after 2-3 iterations, after which the new one is clearly faster.  It is also possible that the new algorithm may be initially faster once the dataset gets sufficiently large.

Comment: This is an interesting finding.  Can you grab the java source code and get more details there?

Comment: Also, it may help to test larger and smaller set sizes.

Comment: One other point: Although Oracle did introduce the `Stream` mechanism to take advantage of mulitcore processors, the other reason for the new API is to support easier processing method chaining, rather than having to do a bunch of looping.

Comment: Diving into `SortedOps` leads to `Arrays.parallelSort`, then because the set is larger than `1<<13`, to `ArraysParallelSortHelpers.FJObject.Sorter` which is some ugly uncommented informatted code with unexplained things like `while (n > g)`, and calls `TimSort.sort` at the end. Note: `Arrays.sort()` directly goes to `TimSort.sort`.

Comment: `pixels.sort(comparator);` is also Java-8-only, mentioning Java 7 here is misleading.

Comment: @glts ah you're right. Although `Collections.sort(list, c);` does simply call `list.sort(c);` (see api source). The benchmark is unaffected. (double-checked by experiment to rule out the compiler overruling methods (like with Math))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seems that you care about the performance during the warm-up stage (namely, first and second sorting after the JVM start). So probably standard JMH benchmark is not suitable for you. That's ok, let's write the benchmark manually. As we are speaking about dozens of milliseconds, naive benchmark which uses `System.nanoTime()` would provide enough precision.

You did not supply your `Comparator` in the question. Simple comparator (like `Comparator.comparingInt(p -> p.x)`) sorts your data much faster, so I assume you have more complex comparator:

```
final Comparator<Point> comparator = Comparator.comparingInt(p -> p.x*p.x + p.y*p.y);
```

It compares points by Euclidean distance from the `(0, 0)` (no need to take square root as it's monotonic function, so order will not change).

Also let's separate the data preparation from the sorting to measure the sorting performance only:

```
private Point[] prepareData() {
    Point[] pixels = new Point[width*height];
    int idx = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            pixels[idx++] = new Point(x, y);
    return pixels;
}
```

I used array instead of `List` to be able to test `Arrays.parallelSort` directly. The plain old sort would be like:

```
public List<Point> sortPlain(Point[] data) {
    List<Point> list = Arrays.asList(data);
    Collections.sort(list, comparator);
    return list;
}
```

The Parallel Stream API based sort would be

```
public List<Point> sortParallelStream(Point[] data) {
    return Stream.of(data).parallel().sorted(comparator).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Let's also add the sequential Stream API version:

```
public List<Point> sortStream(Point[] data) {
    return Stream.of(data).sorted(comparator).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And using `parallelSort` directly:

```
public List<Point> sortParallel(Point[] data) {
    Arrays.parallelSort(data, comparator);
    return Arrays.asList(data);
}
```

Measurement code is not very difficult. [Here](https://gist.github.com/amaembo/9eac0d2c6e4bbe01b946)'s complete implementation. Note that every test should be launched independently, so we test only one mode during the JVM launch. Here's typical results on my machine (i7-4702MQ 2.20GHz, 4 Cores HT = 8 HW threads, Win7 64bit, java 1.8.0_71).

```
Iter  Plain      Parallel   Stream     ParallelStream
#01:  0.38362s   0.37364s   0.28255s   0.47821s
#02:  0.23021s   0.25754s   0.18533s   0.72231s
#03:  0.18862s   0.08887s   0.21329s   0.18024s
#04:  0.19810s   0.06158s   0.68004s   0.12166s
#05:  0.19671s   0.06461s   0.17066s   0.08380s
#06:  0.14796s   0.05484s   0.18283s   0.12931s
#07:  0.16588s   0.04920s   0.21481s   0.13379s
#08:  0.21988s   0.05932s   0.19111s   0.12903s
#09:  0.14434s   0.05123s   0.14191s   0.11674s
#10:  0.18771s   0.06174s   0.14977s   0.07237s
#11:  0.15674s   0.05105s   0.21275s   0.06975s
#12:  0.17634s   0.06353s   0.14343s   0.07882s
#13:  0.15085s   0.05318s   0.16004s   0.11029s
#14:  0.18555s   0.05278s   0.19105s   0.12123s
#15:  0.14728s   0.05916s   0.14426s   0.07235s
#16:  0.18781s   0.05708s   0.21455s   0.07884s
#17:  0.14493s   0.12377s   0.14415s   0.11170s
#18:  0.14395s   0.05100s   0.18201s   0.07878s
#19:  0.14849s   0.05437s   0.14484s   0.08364s
#20:  0.14143s   0.12073s   0.18542s   0.11257s
```

Results for `Plain` and `ParallelStream` tests are somewhat similar to yours: first two iterations are much slower with `ParallelStream` (especially the second one). Also you can note that there's no such effect for direct execution of `Arrays.parallelSort`. Finally non-parallel stream is the slowest. That's because Stream API always uses intermediate buffer for sorting, so it needs more space and time to perform additional copying to the buffer, sorting it, then perform copying to the resulting list.

Why first two iterations for `ParallelStream` are so slow (especiall the second one)? Just because you have quite small starting heap to conveniently place all the intermediate buffers, so several full-gc events occur during the first two iterations which end up in significant delay. If you run your test with `-verbose:gc` you will see for `ParallelStream`:

```
[GC (Allocation Failure)  16384K->14368K(62976K), 0.0172833 secs]
[GC (Allocation Failure)  30752K->30776K(79360K), 0.0800204 secs]
[Full GC (Ergonomics)  30776K->30629K(111104K), 0.4487876 secs]
[GC (Allocation Failure)  63394K->74300K(111104K), 0.0215347 secs]
[Full GC (Ergonomics)  74300K->45460K(167936K), 0.1536388 secs]
[GC (Allocation Failure)  76592K->57710K(179712K), 0.0064693 secs]
#01: 0.41506s
[GC (Allocation Failure)  101713K->103534K(180224K), 0.0567087 secs]
[Full GC (Ergonomics)  103534K->39365K(203776K), 0.5636835 secs]
[GC (Allocation Failure)  84021K->53689K(266752K), 0.0103750 secs]
#02: 0.71832s
```

No more Full GC events after this as heap is sufficiently enlarged now. Compare with `Plain` launch:

```
[GC (Allocation Failure)  16384K->14400K(62976K), 0.0162299 secs]
[GC (Allocation Failure)  30784K->30784K(79360K), 0.0762906 secs]
[Full GC (Ergonomics)  30784K->30629K(111616K), 0.4548198 secs]
#01: 0.43610s
[GC (Allocation Failure)  63397K->58989K(111616K), 0.0330308 secs]
[Full GC (Ergonomics)  58989K->25278K(133120K), 0.2479148 secs]
#02: 0.20753s
```

Only two Full GC which took significantly less time, because there's significantly less garbage.

Let's set the initial heap size to 1Gb with `-Xms1G` to reduce the GC pressure. Now we have completely different results:

```
Iter  Plain      Parallel   Stream     ParallelStream
#01:  0.38349s   0.33331s   0.23834s   0.24078s      
#02:  0.18514s   0.20530s   0.16650s   0.07802s      
#03:  0.16642s   0.10417s   0.16267s   0.11826s      
#04:  0.16409s   0.05015s   0.19890s   0.06926s      
#05:  0.14475s   0.05241s   0.15041s   0.06932s      
#06:  0.14358s   0.05584s   0.14611s   0.06684s      
#07:  0.17644s   0.04913s   0.14619s   0.06716s      
#08:  0.14252s   0.04642s   0.19333s   0.10813s      
#09:  0.14427s   0.04547s   0.14673s   0.06900s      
#10:  0.14696s   0.04634s   0.14927s   0.06712s      
#11:  0.14254s   0.04682s   0.15107s   0.07874s      
#12:  0.15455s   0.09560s   0.19370s   0.06663s      
#13:  0.15544s   0.05133s   0.15110s   0.13052s      
#14:  0.18636s   0.04788s   0.15928s   0.06688s      
#15:  0.14824s   0.04833s   0.15218s   0.06624s      
#16:  0.15068s   0.04949s   0.19183s   0.13925s      
#17:  0.14605s   0.04695s   0.14770s   0.12714s      
#18:  0.14130s   0.04660s   0.14903s   0.15428s      
#19:  0.14695s   0.05491s   0.14389s   0.07467s      
#20:  0.15050s   0.04700s   0.18919s   0.07662s
```

Now results are much more stable even for `Plain` (because we have much less GC pauses) and `ParallelStream` now always better than `Plain` (though it still produces more objects, it's easier to allocate them and collect garbage when you have bigger heap). No full gc events were observed with `-Xms1G` for all four tests

So to conclude:

- ParallelStream produces more garbage and does additional copying which slows down the operation.
- After JVM startup default heap setting is too small, so garbage collector takes quite a lot of time until it decides to sufficiently increase the overall heap size.
- If you want maximal parallel speed, use `Arrays.parallelSort` directly as it sorts in-place. Especially if you know in advance the size of your dataset.

Finally it should be noted that while you are calling `Collections.sort(list, comparator)` as "Java 7 collection sorter" when launched under Java-7 it works 8-10% slower, because `Collections.sort` implementation changed.

Comment: Awesome. Your comparator is equal to the one I used for testing. When I get home, I'll see if your fixes work equaly well for me too.

Comment: `-Xms1G` doesn't seem to make a huge difference, but the warm-up times with `parallelsort` are now down to 0.23s from 0.38s. I see that's better than in your case though. The flag only makes a big difference with streams, and I'll definitely keep that in mind

Comment: @tagir-valeev. Thanks this was great.  As a followup I read a few more articles, one talks about the issues that might happen with competing streams and the use of the ForkJoin Common Thread pool : [Common Fork Join Pool and Streams](https://dzone.com/articles/common-fork-join-pool-and-streams). Should this be factored into the answer and if yes would it change these results?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell with fixed values of `width` and `height`, but in general, parallelizing an algorithm takes additional time resources to set up and tear down, but then runs faster overall on larger data sets that can re-coup that expense over the long haul.

To complete your experiment, I would slowly increase `width` and `height` and see if the parallel algorithm begins to overtake the old algorithm during the "pre-compiled" portion of the test run.

Comment: With smaller sets: 1/2 size: 4x as fast. 1/4 size: 5x. 1/8 size: 8x. With larger sets: 2x size: 1.5x as slow. 4x size: 5x as slow (and weird warmup behavior: 1st time semi-slow, 2nd time very fast, 3rd time slowest)

Comment: How does it compare to the old algorithm for those data sets?  Depending on what the algorithm is doing, slowness could creep in anytime the JVM decides to do garbage collection.

Comment: @Mark Jeronimus: according to your posted numbers, the Java7 style code also has the slowest run the 3rd time. Maybe it has to do with your way of “benchmarking”.

Comment: @Holger The slowness on the 3rd time in the Java 7 style call is probably due to the JIT compiler running.